# How I can fetch the products that one the their owner's nationality is American in AdonisJs?

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, adonis.js

I'm using the AdonisJs framework.

I need to fetch products that one of their owner's nationality is equal to the American.

The product owner has multiple nationalities (American, Canadian or Italian).

I have `Product` and `User` models. In the `Product` model I have an `owner` relation to `User` model.

This is my query. What I must use instead of `whereHas` in the following query:

```
await Product.query()
.where(‘isEnabled’, true)
.whereHas(‘owner’, (builder) => {
builder.where(‘firstNationality’, ‘American’)
builder.orWhere(‘secondNationality’, ‘American’)
builder.orWhere(‘thirdNationalityId’, ‘American’)
});
```

If one the product owners had ‘American’ nationality in `secondNationality` field, all of the enabled products will return.

Comment: If it was me, I'd start with the sql

Comment: What results do you get with your existing code? Provide some sample data and table layouts.

Comment: @miken32 I need to fetch products that one of their owner's nationality is equal to the American